# I want to create a table with primary and foreign key in it but it keeps showing error #1005

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
    book_id INT,
    book_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    genre VARCHAR(25),
    book_name VARCHAR(20),
    invoice_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES Invoice(invoice_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Inventory (
    inventory_id INT,
    category VARCHAR(20),
    selling_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    invoice_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES Invoice(invoice_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice (
    invoice_id INT,
    supp_id INT,
    book_id INT,
    inventory_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (supp_id) REFERENCES Supplier(supp_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book(book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory(inventory_id)
);
```

I wanted to create this table but it keeps showing this error

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
    book_id INT,
    book_price DECIMAL(10, 2),
    genre VARCHAR(25),
    book_name VARCHAR(20),
    invoice_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id) REFERENCES Invoice(invoice_id)
);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1005 - Can't create table `bookmanagement`.`book` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

i tried to make a table with just primary key and the attributes only. but then i have to update the foreign key using alter table but it is so much work to do. what can i do to fic the error and create the table with foreign key in it?

Comment: You can't create the FK before the target table is created.

Comment: Hi Nurul, I'm confused because you have the book statement twice in your question and some cyclic foreign keys. I tryed to reproduce the problem here and it is working: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5eFyLD6VRcmjRWcF5B9wm2/0 Can you plaese give more information.

Comment: As Jens pointed out, you need to break of the cyclic foreign keys as I did in the dbfiddle.

Comment: i opened the link but its empty

Comment: Are you sure that you want one invoice to be related to exactly one book and one inventory, and the book related to only this invoice, and the inventory related to only this invoice? In that case why not make this one table where one row shows the invoice, the book and the inventory?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong link, I had already updated it, it must have overlapped.

Comment: Why a FK in that direction?

Comment: could you explain that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

As [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens) mention in his comment: *You can't create the FK before the target table is created*. So you need to create the tables first and then alter the tables to add FK.

```
CREATE TABLE Book ( 
  book_id INT, 
  book_price DECIMAL(10, 2), 
  genre VARCHAR(25), 
  book_name VARCHAR(20), 
  invoice_id INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (book_id) 
);

CREATE TABLE Inventory ( 
  inventory_id INT, 
  category VARCHAR(20), 
  selling_price DECIMAL(10, 2), 
  invoice_id INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (inventory_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Invoice ( 
  invoice_id INT, 
  supp_id INT, 
  book_id INT, 
  inventory_id INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (invoice_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Book    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Book_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id)     
REFERENCES Invoice (invoice_id);

ALTER TABLE Inventory    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id)     
REFERENCES Invoice (invoice_id);

ALTER TABLE Invoice
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Invoice_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id);
```

Comment: when i try to make another table using the methods you provide, it shows error. why is that?

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the error you're experiencing?

Comment: i try to create this table 

CREATE TABLE Payment ( 
  pay_id INT, 
  Tprice DECIMAL (10, 2), 
  item_qty INT, 
  PRIMARY KEY (pay_id) 
);

CREATE TABLE Orders ( 
  order_id INT, 
  order_qty INT, 
  date DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
);

ALTER TABLE Payment   
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Payment_Orders FOREIGN KEY (order_id)     
REFERENCES Orders (order_id);

Comment: ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Book FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES Book (book_id),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Inventory FOREIGN KEY (inventory_id) REFERENCES Inventory (inventory_id);
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Customer FOREIGN KEY (cust_id) REFERENCES Customer (cust_id);
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Orders_Employee FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES Employee (emp_id);

and it shows me error 
#1072 - Key column 'order_id' doesn't exist in table

Comment: Check in your `Payment` table don't have any `order_id` column.

Comment: Alright solved already. lets say if i already create the table for orders but i didnt put the Foreign key column in it, how can i add it?

Comment: You can alter the table to add new column.

Comment: using this format?

ALTER TABLE Inventory    
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Inventory_Invoice FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id)     
REFERENCES Invoice (invoice_id);

Comment: ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name datatype; in this format.